# animate in jquery

Tags: jquery

i dont know why the element is not animating.. im just following what is the code from jquery.com

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var theW = 249 * slideThumbCount;

$("div.bCont").css("width",theW).css("left","0px");
for(i = 0;i<slideThumbCount;i++)
{
    $("<div>").attr("class","bsThumb bs_" + i).appendTo("div.bCont");
    $("<img />").load(function(){

    }).attr("src","imgDirectory/scrollingImages/img_"+i+".png").appendTo("div.bs_"+i);
}

$("div.bCont").animate({left:50},5000,function(){
    alert('done');
});
});
```

any help please.. :)

Comment: Looks like you're using .load wrong. See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: the load functions works fine.. after the images has been downloaded, the load will takes effect except the animate.. :)

Comment: @Mike - There's *another* `.load()` method for the event: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: ah sir..  my problem is not with the load event.. its the animation.. :)

Comment: @vrynxzent - Yes I know :) The comment was for Mike, that's what the @username portion is for...so they see the message in their notifications :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way:

```
var slideThumbCount = 3; // ???

$(document).ready(function() {

   var theW = 249 * slideThumbCount,
       bCountRef = $("div.bCont"),
       slideThumbCountImage = 0,
       onEndLoadImage = function() {

         // check this
         $(bCountRef).find("div.bsThumb").show();

         $(bCountRef).animate({left: 50}, 5000, function() {
            alert('done');
         });

       };

   $(bCountRef).css("width", theW).css("left", "0px");

   for(i = 0; i <slideThumbCount; i++) {

         $("<img />")
            .attr("src", "imgDirectory/scrollingImages/img_" + i + ".png")
            .load(function(ev){

               $('<div style="display:none">')
                 .attr("class","bsThumb bs_" + i)
                 .append(this) // <-----
                 .appendTo("div.bCont");

               // control for completion of the loading images
               slideThumbCountImage++;
               if (slideThumbCountImage == slideThumbCount)
                  onEndLoadImage();

            });
    }

});
```